# Where is exactly the definition of function-like macros such as CHECK & CHECK_EQ in Caffe?

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

As I noticed, there are lots of function-like macros such as **`CHECK`**, **`CHECK_EQ`**, ... which are frequently used in Caffe headers and source files, for example in *blob.cpp* we have:

```
template <typename Dtype>
void Blob<Dtype>::FromProto(const BlobProto& proto, bool reshape) {
if (reshape) {
  vector<int> shape;
  if (proto.has_num() || proto.has_channels() ||
      proto.has_height() || proto.has_width()) {
    // Using deprecated 4D Blob dimensions --
    // shape is (num, channels, height, width).
    shape.resize(4);
    shape[0] = proto.num();
    shape[1] = proto.channels();
    shape[2] = proto.height();
    shape[3] = proto.width();
  } else {
    shape.resize(proto.shape().dim_size());
    for (int i = 0; i < proto.shape().dim_size(); ++i) {
      shape[i] = proto.shape().dim(i);
    }
  }
  Reshape(shape);
} else {
  CHECK(ShapeEquals(proto)) << "shape mismatch (reshape not set)";
}
// copy data
Dtype* data_vec = mutable_cpu_data();
if (proto.double_data_size() > 0) {
  CHECK_EQ(count_, proto.double_data_size());
  for (int i = 0; i < count_; ++i) {
    data_vec[i] = proto.double_data(i);
  }
} else {
  CHECK_EQ(count_, proto.data_size());
  for (int i = 0; i < count_; ++i) {
    data_vec[i] = proto.data(i);
  }
}
if (proto.double_diff_size() > 0) {
  CHECK_EQ(count_, proto.double_diff_size());
  Dtype* diff_vec = mutable_cpu_diff();
  for (int i = 0; i < count_; ++i) {
    diff_vec[i] = proto.double_diff(i);
  }
} else if (proto.diff_size() > 0) {
  CHECK_EQ(count_, proto.diff_size());
  Dtype* diff_vec = mutable_cpu_diff();
  for (int i = 0; i < count_; ++i) {
    diff_vec[i] = proto.diff(i);
  }
 }
```

Where is exactly the definition of these macros?

Comment: Can't your IDE help you with that?

Comment: At the moment I'm just reading the code without using any IDE. Any special suggestion for Fedora?

Comment: Then I suggest using tools to search the header files of Caffe for the definition of those macros. Macros cannot be "compiled", therefore their definition will always be accessible to you through accessible headers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These macros are part of [Google's `glog`](http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/glog.html) logging library that caffe is using.

Comment: Shai - http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/glog.html is the new link I think that you referred previously.

Comment: @Dharma even better! Thanks!